# Tag synonym request: xarray → python-xarray

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Tag synonym request: [xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xarray) → [python-xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-xarray).

There are currently 2 questions with [xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xarray) and 93 with [python-xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-xarray).  Apparently, `xArray` *could* also refer to [an RFID reader system](http://www.impinj.com/products/gateways/xarray-gateway/) so an alternative would be to retag the existing [xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xarray)-tagged questions and then ban the tag for being ambiguous.

Comment: You really need to synonymize a tag with just 2 question? It would take less time to just retag those.

Comment: BTW, both questions were asked by the same user yesterday... the desire to rise the tag creation privilege to 3k is strong...

Comment: @Braiam It may get created again.

Comment: Doubt so... People needs to look harder.

Comment: @Braiam and I edited 1 question each. [tag:xarray] is gone.

Comment: @approxiblue huh? I am sure I edited the only two questions.. O_O

Comment: @Braiam oh it's a new question... we need to keep an eye on the tag until it's auto-deleted.